# Showing both values and series names in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

[image]

I have a stacked bar chart like in the image above. What i need is to show both series names and values on each bar. How can i do that?

I can show series with this code:

```
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
            new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{0}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to show both of them. The trick is to define each parameters format sequentially. Here is the code:

```
       renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{0} {2}", NumberFormat.getInstance(),NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));
```